# Codeigniter multiple Selection and insertion to a database

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud

i am trying to build a fantansy football league with codeigniter , so far so good but i have a problem with players selection for a specific fantansy team. So far you can see the players with a button to add a player at a time. My question is how do i create a code to select 15 players first and then insert all players to the database instead of  adding one at a time...Here is my controller

```
 public function addPlayer($playerID)
{
        $this->load->model('team_model');
    $data=array(
        'GK1'=>$playerID,
         );

        $this->team_model->add_player($data);
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('transfer_view');
     $this->load->view('footer');


}
```

And My Model

```
              function add_player($data){

           $this->db->insert('fantansyteams',$data);


            }
```

I am using grocery Grud togenerate the views

```
public function transfers($output = null)
{
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $crud->set_theme('datatables');
        $crud->set_table('player');

        $crud->add_action('Add', '', 'team/addPlayer','ui-icon-plus');

        $crud->columns('playerName','value','position');


        $output = $crud->render();



 $this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('transfer_view',$output);
$this->load->view('footer');


}
```

Comment: where is your select statement? You don't need to show us your view, you may want to delete that from the question.

Comment: You can use insert_batch method to insert multiple records at once. Read about $this->db->insert_batch(); at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: @Nish: he is talking about adding multiple players from html form

Comment: @machineaddict thanks for understanding my question,@Nish i want a mechanism to select 15 players from a list of maybe 100 players and add them all to the database. Note: selecting player has to be done one at a time by clicking add button on a form. Please if anyone has an idea i will appreciate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could :

1. Create a model who return all players
2. Create a form with a checkbox list

example :

```
<?php foreach ($players as $player) : ?>
   <input type="checkbox" name="players[]" value="<?= $player->id ?>" > <?= $player->name ?> </input>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I tried this in a php file

```
if (isset($_POST['players'])) {
    // players id list
    var_dump($_POST['players']);
}    

// players list 
echo "<form action='' method='POST' >
        <input type='checkbox' name='players[]' value='1'> Player 1 </input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='players[]' value='2'> Player 2 </input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='players[]' value='3'> Player 3 </input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='players[]' value='15'> Player 15 </input>
        <input type='submit' value='Add'>
      </form>";
```

For example when i choose player 1 and 15 the var_dump result is :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '15' (length=2)
```

I haven't try with codeIgniter but if you have already used codeIgniter's forms that will be easy i think :)

i hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) this is what i was looking for now i have to implement it using codeigniter :-) Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass a array of "playerID" in your controller :

```
$data = array(
           'GK1'=> $playerID, // 'GK1' => array(1,2,3,12...)
        );
```

and in your model  :

```
function add_player($data){
  // foreach players (1,2,3,12...) => insert the player
  foreach($data['GK1'] as $playerID) {
     $this->db->insert('fantansyteams', array('GK1' => $playerID));
  }
}
```

like that you could insert 1, 2, 15 , 100 players

i hope that will help you :)

Comment: @yoam,thanks for helping me.appreciate a lot but my problem was in the view,i want a mechanism where user will choose 15 players by clicking add player button in which all selected 15 players data will be added to the database after they are all selected. Challenge is creating a mechanism that will allow player selection in my view..Thanks again for your support.

Comment: Sorry, i haven't seen the comments just above